# Does Signal Application use Elliptic Curve cryptography for encryption as well?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am studying how Signal application works and as I was reading the [documentation](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/) on how is applied the XEdDSA and VXEdDSA Signature Schemes.

But I kept wondering: if Signal uses elliptic curve for signing a message (as far as I understood), then how does it apply cryptography for encrypting the actual voice and instant messages. Does it use an elliptic curve cryptography scheme with a different key besides the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signal [Double Rachet](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) and [X3DH](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/) protocols for key initialization and session/temptorary encryption key generation. Whilst the XEdDSA and VXEdDSA are used for signing.

All of the schemes are based on X25519 and X448 curves.